# incorrect email preview received date in outlook after migration

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, imap

I exported a PST file from Exchange. Then I imported it into Gsuite with Google Workspace Migration for Microsoft Outlook. In Gmail everything works fine. In Outlook Pro 2016, I have the wrong date displayed in the preview only. But when I open the email, the right date is displayed.

Here are the headers:

```
X-Google-Smtp-Source: XXXX
X-Received: by xxxx:xxx:xxxx:x:xx:xxx:xxxx:xxxx with SMTP id xxxxx;
        Mon, 11 Dec 2023 06:16:10 -0800 (PST)
Received: from 123456789012
    named unknown
    by gmailapi.google.com
    with HTTPREST;
    Mon, 11 Dec 2023 06:16:10 -0800
From: "xxxxxxxx" <xxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com>
To: "xxxxxx" <xxxxx@customDomain.com>
References: <xxxxxxxx@mail.gmail.com> <xxxxxxxxxxx@customDomain.com>
In-Reply-To: <xxxxxxxxxxx@customDomain.com>
Subject: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Date: Wed, 6 Dec 2023 12:08:12 +0100
Message-ID: <xxxxxxxxxxx@mail.gmail.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related;
    boundary="----=_NextPart_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
X-Mailer: Microsoft Outlook 16.0
Thread-Index: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=
Content-Language: fr-be
x-ms-exchange-organization-originalclientipaddress: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
x-ms-exchange-organization-originalserveripaddress: xxx.xx.x.x
x-google-migrated: true
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: CAS2.indiv5.local
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
received-spf: Pass (mailfrom) identity=mailfrom; client-ip=xxx.xx.xxx.xx; helo=mail-wr1-f51.google.com; envelope-from=xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com; receiver=xxxxxxxxxxx@customDomain.com
```

The wrong date is Mon, 11 Dec 2023 06:16:10

The right date is Wed, 6 Dec 2023 12:08:12 +0100

How can I fix it ? I have thousands of emails to fix...

**EDIT:
apparently it's a known bug. See here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/all-mail-imported-to-google-workspace-from-imap/7ed82ae7-9df1-49b4-91fe-bef8896c66c2
None of the proposed solutions worked**

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to [Migrate data from PST files](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7364501?hl=en#zippy=%2Ccalendars-migrated-as-additional-calendars%2Cmessages-missing-or-not-migrated-with-the-correct-sender-or-recipient)?

If so, i found that the below information mentioned in this article:

[Troubleshoot GWMME](https://support.google.com/a/answer/173653?sjid=12338379230534504555-AP#x500&zippy=%2Cmessages-missing-or-migrated-with-an-incorrect-sender-or-recipient%2Cin-gmail-messages-contain-the-wrong-date)

[image]

Comment: I've used this tool, and after a lot of research it looks like you're right about the date format. I ended up changing the display and sorting parameters, choosing the date sent instead of the date received. This trick displays the correct date in the preview. I found this trick on the web.

Comment: Glad to know that it helped. By the way, if you don't mind, you can mark my reply as an answer so that it could be beneficial to others in the community looking for help on similar topics.